# jQuery better events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm writing some app with JavaScript and jQuery and when use events sometimes I need to specify the same event for multiple browsers like  `transitionend`, `webkitTransitionEnd`, `MSTransitionEnd`.

If I use this event in 100 places, it will be hard for me to drop some of them later when browsers remove the prefix. I was wondering if there's some way to put only "transitionend" there and in some other part of the code to add the others, but only once.

Comment: Look at this plugin: https://github.com/georgeadamson/jQuery.prefixfree-events keep in mind that it needs Modernizr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put all the events in one string in your code so there's only one place to manage it. And, if you're using both `.on()` and `.off()`, you can use namespaces too:

```
// declare in a single place available to all your code
// In the future, you can remove any one of these and it will be used
// by all your code
var transitionEvents = "transitionend webkitTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd";
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
$("#myObj").on(transitionEvents, function() {
    // code here
});
```

---

If you also want to remove the event handlers after they fire, you can do use namespacing to help with that:

```
// define all transition events with a namespace
var transitionEvents = "transitionend.tend webkitTransitionEnd.tend MSTransitionEnd.tend";
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
$("#myObj").on(transitionEvents, function() {
    // remove all transition event handlers using the namespace
    $(this).off(".tend");

    // put code here for the end of the transition
});
```

---

You could also make your own jQuery plug-in method that handles this for you:

```
// method to handle transition end and remove all handlers when the event fires
jQuery.fn.onTransitionEnd = function(fn) {
    var transitionEvents = "transitionend.tend webkitTransitionEnd.tend MSTransitionEnd.tend";
    this.on(transitionEvents, function(e) {
        $(this).off(".tend");
        return fn.call(this, e);
    });
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
$("#myObj").onTransitionEnd(function(e) {
    // code here for the end of the transition
});
```